# Workflow doesn't start when Item is created

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have an initial workflow that is independent of this discussion where an item gets copied into list1. After this occurs, the workflow in question starts as expected since I have the workflow set to start when an item is created within list1. The item gets modified (an update of a status). After the item is modified, the same workflow kicks off because I also have this workflow set to start when an item is changed in list1. Due to the status change, the item is copied into list2 and deleted from list1. Based on similar logic within list2 where a status change occurs, another workflow copies the item back into list1. While this item is seem in list1, the workflow associated with list1 does not kick off again. I have logging at the top of the workflow with no conditions around it. It is definitely not getting hit as nothing showing up in the Workflow history.

I'm trying to figure out why the process works the first time but not the second? If the item is deleted and then copied in again, does that not satisfy the condition for a new item being created to kick off the workflow?

Thanks!

Comment: any error appears?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this almost 4 years after the initial posting, so it's unlikely to help OP, but hopefully it will help fellow Googlers.

I believe the problem you're running into is SharePoint not allowing recursive workflows. You can see if that's happening by looking in ULS. If a workflow triggers itself to run again, it's viewed as a potential endless loop and stopped explicitly to prevent that from being possible.

Looking at the logic in your workflow, I do not see a clear end to when these workflows are supposed to stop firing. (List1 copies item to List2 triggering WF, item updated triggering WF, item updated again triggering WF, etc.).